# Firebase crashlytics error loading event trends

Tags: crashlytics, crashlytics-android

After migrating my app from fabric's crashlytics to firebase's crashlytics, Firebase crashlytics dashboard only show crash-free statistics (that not match with fabric data) and event trends is error. try reload the page several time but the result is same. like this Image below

[image: firebase crashlytics event trends error]

any idea what should I do to make my crashlytics data appear in firebase dashboard?

Comment: I have this problem too since today at least..., nothing to do if you followed the guides I think

Comment: thanks @djleop. you are right, now the data appear on dashboard